# Make List of Unique Objects in Python

Tags: python, list, unique

It is possible to 'fill' an array in Python like so:

```
> [0] * 10
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I wanted to use this sample principle to quickly create a list of similar objects:

```
> a = [{'key': 'value'}] * 3
> a
[{'key': 'value'}, {'key': 'value'}, {'key': 'value'}]
```

But it appears these objects are linked with one another:

```
> a[0]['key'] = 'another value'
> a
[{'key': 'another value'}, {'key': 'another value'}, {'key': 'another value'}]
```

Given that Python does not have a `clone()` method (it was the first thing I looked for), **how would I create unique objects without the need of declaring a `for` loop and calling `append()` to add them?**

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, the ``copy.copy()`` function can be used to "clone" many kinds of existing Python objects.  In addition, a number of mutable objects (deques, sets, dicts) have a ``copy()`` method.  The list object grew a ``copy()`` method in Python 3.

Comment: Since the question was closed, I'll have to use a comment to answer the interesting part of your question, "how can you do this without a for-loop and append?"  Here is what you could do:  ``d = {'key': 'value'}; import copy; from itertools import repeat; a = list(map(copy.copy, repeat(d, 10)))``.  When a ``copy()`` method is available, it would be faster still to use *starmap* thusly: ``a = list(starmap(d.copy, repeat((), 10)))``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple list comprehension should do the trick:

```
>>> a = [{'key': 'value'} for _ in range(3)]
>>> a
[{'key': 'value'}, {'key': 'value'}, {'key': 'value'}]
>>> a[0]['key'] = 'poop'
>>> a
[{'key': 'poop'}, {'key': 'value'}, {'key': 'value'}]
```